# append and prepend with simple-form and bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, haml, simple-form

I need to be able to use simple form input tag using a bootstrap append and prepend. I can do it with one easily but not getting them both to work. Is this possible.

here is what I have using haml this is for a prepend but I need another one on the end so using append.

```
= f.input :domain, wrapper: :prepend, label: false do
  %span.add-on
    %span.icon @
  = f.input_field :domain
```

Answer (score 0):

simple_form only has wrappers for `:prepend` or `:append` but not both at the same time.  Luckily, it's really easy to build a custom wrapper that does both.  Just copy & paste one of the wrappers and modify it slightly.

Here's my solution:

config/initializers/simple_form.rb

```
config.wrappers :prepend_append, :tag => 'div', :class => "control-group", :error_class => 'error' do |b|
  b.use :html5
  b.use :placeholder
  b.use :label
  b.wrapper :tag => 'div', :class => 'controls' do |input|
    input.wrapper :tag => 'div', :class => 'input-prepend input-append' do |pa|
      pa.use :input
    end
    input.use :hint,  :wrap_with => { :tag => 'span', :class => 'help-block' }
    input.use :error, :wrap_with => { :tag => 'span', :class => 'help-inline' }
  end
end
```

And, in your view:

```
= f.input :url, wrapper: :prepend_append, label: false do
  %span.add-on something
  = f.input_field :url, input_html: { class: "span2" }
  %span.add-on something
```

And finally, add this to your css:

```
.input-prepend .add-on,
.input-append input {
  float: left;
}
```

Hope that helps.  Be sure to restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do it is this:

```
<%= f.input :field, :wrapper_html => {class: "input-prepend input-append"} do %>
  <span class="add-on">$</span>
    <%= f.input_field :field %>
  <span class="add-on">%</span>
<% end %>
```